# ElasticSearch logfile start explanation

Tags: elasticsearch, warnings, dependency-management, logfile, discovery

Can anyone please explain the ElasticSearch logfile? what do these warnings mean?

```
[2020-08-21T14:57:40,341][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [inov.telecom.mu] no plugins loaded
[2020-08-21T14:57:40,425][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [inov.telecom.mu] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [5gb], net total_space [6.9gb], types [rootfs]
[2020-08-21T14:57:40,426][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [inov.telecom.mu] heap size [1gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2020-08-21T14:57:40,664][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [inov.telecom.mu] node name [inov.telecom.mu], node ID [K8DOuHAIQDyc_iJ7L6GvUA], cluster name [elasticsearch]
[2020-08-21T14:57:51,336][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [inov.telecom.mu] [controller/23136] [Main.cc@114] controller (64 bit): Version 7.9.0 (Build 2639177a4c3ad6) Copyright (c) 2020 Elasticsearch BV
[2020-08-21T14:57:52,249][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [inov.telecom.mu] parsed [0] roles from file [/etc/elasticsearch/roles.yml]
[2020-08-21T14:57:55,188][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [inov.telecom.mu] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2020-08-21T14:57:56,382][WARN ][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] [inov.telecom.mu] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
[2020-08-21T14:57:57,479][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [inov.telecom.mu] initialized
[2020-08-21T14:57:57,480][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [inov.telecom.mu] starting ...
[2020-08-21T14:57:57,909][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [inov.telecom.mu] publish_address {10.0.2.15:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2020-08-21T14:57:59,075][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [inov.telecom.mu] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2020-08-21T14:57:59,106][INFO ][o.e.c.c.Coordinator      ] [inov.telecom.mu] cluster UUID [_h6yYXorQk-1XlY01ZoJiw]
[2020-08-21T14:57:59,583][INFO ][o.e.c.s.MasterService    ] [inov.telecom.mu] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[{inov.telecom.mu}{K8DOuHAIQDyc_iJ7L6GvUA}{7AayvvDtTfmprPSF4KloDA}{10.0.2.15}{10.0.2.15:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=3973541888, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20} elect leader, _BECOME_MASTER_TASK_, _FINISH_ELECTION_], term: 9, version: 83, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{inov.telecom.mu}{K8DOuHAIQDyc_iJ7L6GvUA}{7AayvvDtTfmprPSF4KloDA}{10.0.2.15}{10.0.2.15:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=3973541888, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}
[2020-08-21T14:57:59,912][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] [inov.telecom.mu] master node changed {previous [], current [{inov.telecom.mu}{K8DOuHAIQDyc_iJ7L6GvUA}{7AayvvDtTfmprPSF4KloDA}{10.0.2.15}{10.0.2.15:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=3973541888, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}]}, term: 9, version: 83, reason: Publication{term=9, version=83}
[2020-08-21T14:58:00,180][INFO ][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] [inov.telecom.mu] publish_address {10.0.2.15:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
[2020-08-21T14:58:00,181][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [inov.telecom.mu] started
[2020-08-21T14:58:00,774][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [inov.telecom.mu] license [dd0be5a0-66a5-4eca-9661-88c074a53fc7] mode [basic] - valid
[2020-08-21T14:58:00,776][INFO ][o.e.x.s.s.SecurityStatusChangeListener] [inov.telecom.mu] Active license is now [BASIC]; Security is disabled
[2020-08-21T14:58:00,826][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [inov.telecom.mu] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
[2020-08-21T14:58:03,803][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [inov.telecom.mu] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.kibana_task_manager_1][0]]]).
[2020-08-21T15:03:25,952][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetadataIndexTemplateService] [inov.telecom.mu] adding template [.management-beats] for index patterns [.management-beats]
```

Comment: There's a single WARN `dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually` is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

This WARN is a default value for this setting - you can ignore this message.